# How to merge two columns in R with a specific symbol?

Tags: r, merge, symbols

I have a table read in R as follows:

```
column1 column2
A        B
```

What is the command to be used to match two columns together as follows?

```
Column 3
A_B
```

Answer (score 65):

I'm a bit unsure what you mean by "merge", but is this what you mean?

```
> DF = data.frame(A = LETTERS[1:10], B = LETTERS[11:20])
> DF$C = paste(DF$A, DF$B, sep="_")
> head(DF)
  A B  C
1 A K A_K
2 B L B_L
3 C M C_M
4 D N D_N
```

Or equivalently, as @daroczig points out:

```
 within(DF, C <- paste(A, B, sep='_'))
```

Comment: To return NA in cases where one or both elements is missing, you could use an `ifelse()` statement as follows: `within(DF, C <- ifelse(is.na(A)==TRUE | is.na(B)==TRUE, NA, paste(A, B, sep='_')))`.

Comment: Is there a way in Paste to auto ignore NA Values?

Answer (score 15):

My personal favourite involves making use of the [**`unite`**](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/58498_dd3b603ba4fb4b469bb1c57b5a951c39.html#unite-function) in `tidyr`:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(colA = sample(LETTERS, 10),
                 colB = sample(LETTERS, 10))
# packs: pipe + unite
require(magrittr); require(tidyr)


# Unite
df %<>%
  unite(ColAandB, colA, colB, remove = FALSE)
```

## Results

```
> head(df, 3)
  ColAandB colA colB
1      G_F    G    F
2      J_E    J    E
3      N_Q    N    Q
```

### Side notes

Personally, I find the `remove = TRUE / FALSE` functionality of unite very useful. In addition `tidyr` firs the `dplyr` workflow very well and plays well with [**`separate`**](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/58498_dd3b603ba4fb4b469bb1c57b5a951c39.html#separate-function) in case you change your mind about the columns being merged. On the same lines, if `NA`s are the problem introducing `na.omit` to your workflow would enable you to conveniently drop the undesirable rows before creating the desired column.