# sum/average different columns in dataframe R

Tags: r

I have 4 columns in a data frame

```
a <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4), b=c(4,5,6,7), c=c(7,6,5,4), d=c(8,4,3,2))
```

I want to average first two columns and last two columns to get one data frame with two columns of same nrows with average of first two columns and last two columns

expected output:

```
5 15
7 10
9 8
11 6
```

Comment: possible duplicate here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559467/how-to-merge-two-columns-in-r-with-a-specific-symbol take a look it might do what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce your output (which is sum, not mean):

```
library(plyr)
ddply(a, .(), summarise, first=a+b, second=c+d)[,-1]
```

It produces:

```
  first second
1     5     15
2     7     10
3     9      8
4    11      6
```

To make `data.frame` with averages:

```
ddply(a, .(), summarise, first=(a+b)/2, second=(c+d)/2)[,-1]
```

Output is:

```
  first second
1   2.5    7.5
2   3.5    5.0
3   4.5    4.0
4   5.5    3.0
```

If you don't know columns' names code can be modified like this:

```
ddply(a, .(), summarise, first=a[,1]+a[,2], second=a[,3]+a[,4])[,-1]
```

Here you access columns by its order. Alternatively, you can simply run `names(a) <- letters[1:4]` prior to `ddply()`.

`ddply` is very flexible function, you can specify grouping variables as second argument and get grouped results. But if the case is as simple as in the question you can call `summarise` directly:

```
summarise(a, first=a+b, second=c+d)                 # if you know columns' names
summarise(a, first=a[,1]+a[,2], second=a[,3]+a[,4]) # if you don't know columns' names
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. but i dont have any columns names. I gave above as an example. All i know to add first two columns and last two columns. How would i pass that information?

Comment: Simply run `names(a) <- letters[1:4]` prior to `ddply` to assign names

Comment: @redmionds, summarise(a, first=a[,1]+a[,2], second=a[,3]+a[,4]), is throwing error -> "Error in a[, 1] incorrect number of dimensions"

Comment: @user1631306, I think it's because `data.frame` `a` has column named `a`.