# How to join three columns in R (i.e. How to do a Google Sheets "Join" function in R)

Tags: r

I've got the following code in Google Spreadsheets: `=JOIN(" ",B2:E2)`

It merges three columns: 'First Name',  'Middle Initial',   'Last Name' in order to get me a new column, which I call 'Unique Name'

Now, Google Sheets doesn't let me join as an arrayformula (`=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" ",$B$2:$E))` returns error: "JOIN range must be a single row or a single column."

So, I'm trying to figure out how to do this in R.

My dataframe (I think I'm using that term correctly) name in R is "NSCH", and the columns are named 'First.Name', 'Middle.Initial', 'Last.name', 'Name.Suffix'

Other search terms: How to do a (google sheets|excel) "join" (function|formula) in R

Comment: Bah I also didnt realize but you pointed to another stack overflow answer that addressed your question  - **in your own answer**. Don't do this - it already has an answer!

Comment: Hi Cris, thanks for your comment. The answer that @thelatemail found is perfect - but I think that one reason I wasn't able to find it was that it uses the word "concatenate" instead of "join". (Meanqhile, the answer that I found myself took me some time to find, and contains extraneous information that was not relevant to the question). Given that, is it still a duplicate question?

Comment: Hi Josh - yes it is, concatenate is another (better) name for join, so your answer is a duplicate. The core of your question is "how do I concantenate two strings in r", not "how do I replicate the google join function" (even though the latter is how you asked). I would also say that the answer you linked is one of the simpler ones on the site - it is hard for me to see any extraneous information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly easier might be `unite` from `tidyr`. Something like this:

```
library(tidyr)

unite(NSCH,
      Unique.Name,
      First.Name, Middle.Initial, Last.name, Name.Suffix,
      sep = ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the following syntax  [How to merge two columns in R with a specific symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559467/how-to-merge-two-columns-in-r-with-a-specific-symbol)

```
DF$C = paste(DF$A, DF$B, sep="_")
```

Where DF = Dataframe name, and [A|B|C] = Column name

For my data frame, this would be:

```
NSCH$Unique.Name = paste(NSCH$First.Name, NSCH$Middle.Initial, NSCH$Last.Name, sep=" ")
```

In order to see the change in the data frame in my version of RStudio, I have to run the View (note the capital V) command:

```
View(NSCH)
```

I also had four possible items instead of three in my dataset, so to get a column with the true UniqueName, which joins all four columns I used the following syntax:

```
NSCH$Unique.Name = paste(NSCH$First.Name, NSCH$Middle.Initial, NSCH$Last.Name, NSCH$Name.Suffix, sep=" ")
View(NSCH)
```

Comment: I don't know why you are referring to yourself in the second person - answering your own questions is fairly encouraged here, no need to pretend it is not what is going on

Comment: You could also save a bit of typing by doing something like `do.call(paste, c(NSCH[c("First.Name", "Middle.Initial", "Last.Name")], sep="_") )`