# Mean and SD from a data frame of non numeric values

Tags: r

I want to find the mean and standard deviation of the values present in a data frame,

```
> print(Data)
  Description   X24386
0 A             65.8751
1 A             152.6380
2 A             90.0535
3 A             NA
4 B             74.4218
5 B             77.7234
6 B             79.7033
7 B             72.5045
8 C             79.3704
9 C             81.9795
```

Using the dcast aggregate I could group the data and find the mean

```
result<-dcast(D, Description ~ . ,fun.aggregate=mean)   

> print(result)
  Description        .
1 B                  76.08
2 C                  80.67
3 A                   NA
```

Since a non-numeric value is present in one of the rows of group A, the mean is NA.

I'm looking for a syntax using which I can compute the mean of the columns that contain numeric values. I looked at the answers given in posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615922/aggregate-r-sum)

Since I want to find the mean for a specific column I am facing trouble in implementing it for my case.

Also, I would like to ask for suggestions on how

```
result<-dcast(D, Description ~ . ,fun.aggregate=mean)
```

can be modified to print the standard deviations in the column next to the mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `na.rm = TRUE` argument for `mean` (see `?mean`) to the end of the `dcast`:

```
dcast(D, Description ~ . ,fun.aggregate=mean, na.rm = TRUE)

  Description         .
1           A 102.85553
2           B  76.08825
3           C  80.67495
```

If you want standard deviation too, I'd switch to using `dplyr` so you can group the data then summarise as many times as you like.

```
library(dplyr)
D %>% 
  group_by(Description) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(X24386, na.rm = TRUE), 
            SD   = sd(X24386, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Description  Mean    SD
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
1 A           103.  44.8 
2 B            76.1  3.23
3 C            80.7  1.84
```

You could use `aggregate` too:

```
aggregate(. ~ Description, data = D, FUN = function(x) c(mn = mean(x), sd = sd(x)))

  Description  X24386.mn  X24386.sd
1           A 102.855533  44.775766
2           B  76.088250   3.233297
3           C  80.674950   1.844912
```

Comment: note that if `agg` is the result of your `aggregate`, you cannot do `agg[, "X24386.mn"]`, it will throw an error. This is because `agg` only has *two* columns, the second is a `matrix` with columns `mn` and `sd`. See `str(agg)` and the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064202/apply-several-summary-functions-on-several-variables-by-group-in-one-call).

Comment: Is there any command that can give the output in the following format,

   `Description  X24386.mn ± X24386.sd`
    `1           A 102.855533 ± 44.775766` 
    `2           B  76.088250 ± 3.233297`
    `3           C  80.674950 ± 1.844912`

In short, I wish to output the mean and standard deviation in a single column so that it will be easy to export the data to excel.

Comment: I found some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559467/how-to-merge-two-columns-in-r-with-a-specific-symbol) that show how to merge two columns with a symbol in between. Since the second element is a matrix I'm not able to apply those steps. Any suggestions?